# Variable not changing, even though it is being set

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am attempting to create a simple add-on for Google Docs that allows you to view captures from the Wayback Machine.

I am attempting to set a variable that can be accessed by every function in the script, however, it appears as if it is only being set in the function's scope.

The variables are initialized...

```js
let capurl = "example.com";
let capyear = "1996";
let capmonth = "01";
let capday = "01";
```

...and the function attempts to set them...

```js
function archdisplay(url, datestring) {
  capurl = url;
  capyear = datestring.substr(0,4);  // [YYYY]-MM-DD
  capday = datestring.substr(8);     // YYYY-MM-[DD]
  capmonth = datestring.substr(5,2); // YYYY-[MM]-DD
  ui.alert(capmonth+"/"+capday+"/"+capyear); // outputs correctly?
  ...
}
```

...however, it just accesses example.com again. Any ideas?

Comment: Use var instead of let. Provide your full code of where you initialize the variables.

Comment: @Mario I was previously using `var`, but that didn't work either. Switching to `let` was a debug measure. Also, what do you mean "full code"? Thanks!

Comment: Hi there! I want to add that @Mario is likely asking for a [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we all can study the issue. I can't find the error by using the fragment of code shown in the question, so please share a replicable code. Also, are you taking any steps not declared in the question?